# Bootstrap4: dropdown inside sticky table cells

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, dropdown, sticky

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to build a table with an action column that contains a dropdown menu. I want that column to be sticky so that if there is a horizontal scroll it's always visible.

The problem is that when I open the dropdown every cell after the one I open seems to be on a different layer and always sits above the dropdown. The ones before sit below and the ones after sit above.

I tried playing around with the cell and dropdown z-index but I can't seem to fix this.

```css
.action {
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          <th scope="col">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
          <td class="action" style="position: sticky">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Menu
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
          <td class="action" style="position: sticky">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Menu
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
          <td class="action">
            <div class="dropdown" style="position: sticky">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Menu
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"This code is here only to bypass SO's validation"* Please consider yourself having been warned not to do that again. The quality filters are there for a reason, and knowingly bypassing them is considered to be abusive behavior, which may lead to restrictions on your ability to post questions in the future. If you have questions about how to include code or snippets in your question, please check the [help] and/or ask a question on [Meta].

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code to css, e.g.:

```
.table td.action {
    position: sticky !important;
    right: 0;
}
```

You can add also(to fix the position of dropdown):

```
.table .dropdown-menu.show {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 36px, 0px) !important;
}
```

Read also: https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/

```js
$( ".dropdown" ).click(function() {
 $( "td.action" ).css( "z-index", 0 );
 $( this ).parent().css( "z-index", 1 );      
});
```

```css
.table .action {
    position: sticky !important;
    right: 0;
}
/*Only to show horizontal scrolling:*/
.table td, .table th {
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          <th class="action" scope="col">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
          <td class="action">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Menu
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
          <td class="action">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Menu
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
          <td class="action">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Menu
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I want to action column to be fixed if there is horizontal scroll... That's the whole point of the question...

Comment: Check now, I have added the 'action' class also for th (Actions) and changed the css for .action elements

Comment: The dropdown still stays below the buttons...

Comment: It stays below the buttons because next table row covers previous row.
You can try adding this code:
```button.dropdown-toggle {
position: absolute;
}```

```.dropdown-menu {
position: relative !important;
margin-bottom: 35px;
}```

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          <th scope="col">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
          <td class="action" >
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"  type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Menu
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu"   style="z-index:1;position: relative;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item"   href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item"   href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
          <td class="action" >
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"   type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Menu
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu"   style="z-index:1;position: relative;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item"   href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item"   href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
          <td class="action">
            <div class="dropdown" >
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"    type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Menu
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index:1;position: relative;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item"  href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

please check at :https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/y9v0rLwt/

Comment: No dice! The `action` column must be sticky. See https://jsfiddle.net/m0gnak27/

Comment: @GonçaloMarrafa what do you mean by it beign sticky ...my solution is catering to what you asked for....please explain..

Comment: the action row is inside the table how can they be sticky..

Comment: I want the action row to be sticky because if there is horizonta scroll I want it to always be visible. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/mguLh6bs/